# How do I fix a download issue when updating?

Tags: 11.04, update-manager, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

For some reason every time I try to update by terminal, synaptic, and update manager I get this error message and I cannot update all the data I need.

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Netbook 10.04 _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20100429.4)/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu-Netbook 10.04 _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20100429.4)/dists/lucid/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-dx-team/une/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-dx-team/une/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lorenzo-carbonell/atareao/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/lorenzo-carbonell/atareao/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/meebey/ppa/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/gnome3-builds/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/gnome3-builds/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: You've mentioned that you're upgrading to 11.04, but your log indicates that it's downloading 10.04. Can you edit to clarify which version you're running, and to which you're upgrading?

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Update Manager click the "Settings" button.  This will open your Software Sources windows:

1. Untick the "CD-ROM" option - in my case it is "Ubuntu 10.10"
2. Go through the list and untick all your PPAs
3. Then click close
4. Check that you can now update successfully.

[image: enter image description here][1]

If you still cannot update then change your download mirror to another server:
[image: enter image description here][2]

Comment: thanx, it worked and i have no problems now :P help apretiated