# Cannot install automake and libboost-all-dev

Tags: 12.04, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix a download issue when updating?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60062/how-do-i-fix-a-download-issue-when-updating)

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and installed it in a VMware workstation. and I've been using all the installation commands:

```
sudo apt-get install automake
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

and some others,
but it kept on saying:

```
E: unable to locate package automake
E: unable to locate package libboost-all-dev
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install automake
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Comment: Please consider adding comments to your answer. This makes it easier, especially for less experienced users. apt-get update might not be enough here.

Comment: Still doesn't find the package.