# Cannot install automake and libboost-all-dev because I can't fetch repository updates

Tags: 12.04, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install automake and libboost-all-dev](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193114/cannot-install-automake-and-libboost-all-dev)

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and installed it in a VMware workstation. and I've been using all the installation commands:

```
sudo apt-get install automake
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

and some others, but it kept on saying:

```
E: unable to locate package automake
E: unable to locate package libboost-all-dev
```

I also wrote the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and the reply was some error messages:

```
unable to connect...
W: failed to fetch ...
W: some index failed to download
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please do not duplicate your own question.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to not have internet access. Make sure that your network (in the guest system) is working properly, has proper DN resolution and can access the outside world using HTTP.

Comment: the internet is working properly. I'm using it rite now

Comment: Are you accessing the Internet from the *host* or from the *guest*? In any case, go to Ubuntu Software centre and try reinstall the source.